# Loading indicator when uploading files to AWS S3 via Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a file input in my Angular 5 form that uploads a file into an AWS S3 bucket.

My html looks like this:

```
<input type="file" (change)="fileEvent($event)" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload" />
{{this.isLoading}}
```

and this is my component:

```
isLoading: boolean = false;

fileEvent(fileInput: any) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    s3.upload({ Key: file.name, Bucket: bucketName, Body: file, ACL: 'public-read' }, function (err, data) {
      this.isLoading = false;
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, 'there was an error uploading your file');
      }
    });
  }
```

The isLoading variable changes to true successfully when I start the upload, but does not change back to false when I finish.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following snippet:

```
s3.upload({ Key: file.name, Bucket: bucketName, Body: file, ACL: 'public-read' }, function (err, data) {
  this.isLoading = false;
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, 'there was an error uploading your file');
  }
});
```

the `this` of `this.isLoading` is actually referring to the anonymous function itself, and not the bound object. Keep an old reference to the same:

```
fileEvent(fileInput: any) {
    self = this;
    self.isLoading = true;
    s3.upload({ Key: file.name, Bucket: bucketName, Body: file, ACL: 'public-read' }, function (err, data) {
      self.isLoading = false;
      if (err) {
        console.log(err, 'there was an error uploading your file');
      }
    });
  }
```

and it should work.